# Search not Working on other sites

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have two sites:

On my Alternate Access Mappings

```
http://intranet.mymainsite.local - Default
http://intranet.myothersite.com - Intranet
```

I add the site on my Search Service Application and Start Full Crawl.
When i try to search a document in SharePoint using the Document Library App, the search will work on Default Zone I could see the file/document I've search. But when searching for a document on the other site which is the Intranet the search does not give any data even if the document exist.

I also added the Intranet site to the IIS Bindings in the Default Zone.

How to fix my Intranet Zone to make use of search function?

Comment: Did you add the "myothersite" to the Content Sources of the Search Service Application?

Comment: Yes I only added Intranet zone, does it affect if i'm using https?

Answer (score 0):

When I view my Crawl Log the Intranet and default Zone, when tried to search the successfully crawled pages, it basically returns the pages I've searched so, I just added the site in the Manage Crawl Rules and include document and web pages to be crawl and my search functions are doing great. Thanks for your help